# How can retrieve click data from dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery

This code loop appends dynamically created li's to #carList

```
for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
                var carNow = car[i];

                $('#carList').append("<li>" + carNow.carName +
     </li>").data("item", {
                    index: i
                });

            };
```

This code binds a click eventListener to ul#carList. I know tht I must use the JQuery object ($(this)) to expose the data on the clicked li but I'm not sure exactly how..Any help is appreciated

```
 $('#carList').on('click', "li", one);

 function one() {
            controller.setCurrentCar($(this));
            carView.render();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to each `<li>` then put a click event on that class.

```js
var car = [{
  carName:"Subaru",
  model:"X1"
}, 
{
  carName:"Alfa Romero",
  model:"car2"
}]

$(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    var carNow = car[i];

    $('#carList').append("<li class='car-item'>" + carNow.carName +
      "</li>").data("item", {
      index: i
    });
  };
  //click event for class .car-item
  $(".car-item").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).text());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on the car names:<br>
<ul id="carList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the same [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method you used to set the data to retrieve it using the same string you used to set it

```
$(this).data("item");
```